# How to send users in the right direction before they post asking for the wrong technique?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-wiki, synonym-request

I often see users asking for batch programming on Windows and they try to solve rather complex tasks. A lot of these tasks would be better solved with a different technique that is also built-in to Windows, but often users simply don't know it exists.

Are there means to attach a kind of "redirect" to a tag ? In this situation the user should be informed that he is better off using the socalled Windows Scripting Host. Or is this a situation where a Wiki could be linked to the tag and one of the first lines could describe the alternatives ? I only recently learned about the "tag-wiki", but I think it might be too hidden.

I have an example for such a post. The OP confirmed he didn't know of the alternative:
[What's wrong with this Batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682528/whats-wrong-with-this-batch-file?noredirect=1#comment49426016_30682528)

Comment: How will you know their intent unless you read it?

Comment: Independent off whether they are trying to find the reason for a batch not working or if they try create one anew my assumption (I chose that word on purpose) is that they are better off creating or re-creating it with WSH because it is more like a highlevel programming language which makes the code clearer

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/

Comment: I get your point but the idea is to give them additional info. They are travelling by horse and we already are in the car age. They should know that cars exist and which advantage they have. After that they can judge if a horse   is still what they need or not. They shall not be patronized, only informed.

Comment: @Marged the post random linked seems to cover this issue.  The idea is when the `X` of the `Y` problem is clear, then answer for `X`.  The point is you are solving the problem of the user even if it is different than what they think the problem is.